# Can i get Lydia to only use her bow?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

On occasion Lydia will switch to using a bow, i know it's not related to what i wield as sometimes we both have swords, sometimes we both have bows and sometimes one of us has a sword and the other a bow.

sometimes when i'm killing someone/something me and her have pincer them and when they die i do another attack hitting her or she walks in front of me when i'm using magic or a staff, this gets annoying at times cause i use up energy (especially if it's from a staff) but more importantly it looks bad on me as her wife, blasting her with magic from behind or stabbing her after the enemy is dead (i am aware that spouses are set to essential but it still looks bad)

I am wondering if i can get Lydia to always use her bow since this way she plays a support role. i don't mind having to use a mod to do this.

NOTE: i have all DLC so mod requirements like that are no problem

Comment: vanilla: I don't think so. She's a melee character so she would most likely prefer it. However, that being said if you take any weapons you have given her, and give her a stronger bow, she may prefer the bow instead.

Comment: I wonder if you can pick-pocket her weapons, if you have the perk for it, then make sure all she has is a bow. Tho, I've never tested that myself.

Comment: I believe that can be done. The other option would be console commands (possibly). I'm a console gamer though, so I'm not too learned in the ways of the PC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the vanilla game; no.

With mods; possibly, depending on the mods that are out there.

Basically there are "Build-types" with the AI in the game, that lean towards certain traits in the character skill tree. Strength, Sneaking, Magic, etc. Lydia is a Strength/Melee character type, therefore she would *prefer* to use melee weapons.

That being said, if you give an AI a weapon of greater damage output, they will *prefer* that weapon. So if you take any high-damage melee weapons away from her, and give her a high-damage bow instead, she will *prefer* the bow. However, with the AI the way it is, this does not have very much functionality, as she is primarily a melee AI, so she'll tend to whip out her sword and swing that around anyway.

So if you want to achieve this, mods are your best bet.

**EDIT:** You could try using commands, or pickpocketing her to remove her base equipment, leaving her only with her bow and arrows. However, should you give her a melee weapon to carry, she will likely use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

I belive you can. If you ask to trade some items, take all of her melee weapons away from her, give her some arrows and a bow and she should use it.

If this doesn't work give her a bow that is stronger than her other weapons. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Just go into her inventory and take all of the melee weapons she has. This will cause her to use her bow as it the only weapon she has.